# How do I paste multiple selected lines one to one in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, copy-paste

I have two files, and I want to paste the lines from file A in to the multi-selections of file B.

File A contains the lines:

```py
foo0
foo1
foo2
foo3
```

And file B with the lines:

```py
var0 = "foo0"
somevar = False
var1 = "foo0"
some_other_var = False
var2 = "foo0"
some_code_I_have_to_work_around = False
var3 = "foo0"
```

I want to paste the lines from file A in to the values of the variables in file B so that it looks like this:

```py
var0 = "foo0"
somevar = False
var1 = "foo1"
some_other_var = False
var2 = "foo2"
some_code_I_have_to_work_around = False
var3 = "foo3"
```

But I keep getting output that looks like:

```py
var0="foo0
foo1
foo2
foo3"
somevar = False
var1="foo0
foo1
foo2
... <snip>
```

How do I tell PyCharm I just want it to paste exactly the number of lines from file A in to the values of file B without pasting ALL the lines from my copy in to each of my multi-selections?

Comment: What are those files? Data files? Python code? I am thinking of syntax highlighting here - is it correct or not (it can be turned off [with ```lang-none](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use multi-selection in **both** the source copy, and destination paste.

*[Select multiple non-contiguous ranges](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html#multiselection)*

I use the [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) hotkey mapping, so my key for "select next occurrence of thing" is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. The default PyCharm is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, according to the documentation.

I was trying to paste a *single* selection into a multi-selection, hence PyCharm was pasting my *single* selection in to the multi-selection like I asked it to.

I had thought that PyCharm would behave like Sublime Text and automatically recognized that the exact number of lines in my single selection matched the number of lines in my multi-selection, and intelligently placed them.